# Converting Java while loop to Stream for performance

Tags: java, stream

I have the following code, which has performance issues due to having to convert a long Stream to an Array. The Board.getReachables() method returns a stream, so it would be much more performant to be able to do this while loop using streams. I am however, unsure as to how to proceed.

```
 int counter = 1;
 while (check(board, counter)) {
   for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
     if (board[i] == counter) {
       for (Pos reach2 :
            Board.getReachables(currentTurn.getBoard().pos(i),
                                currentTurn.getBoard())
                 .toArray(Pos[]::new)) {
         if (board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(reach2)] == 0) {
           board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(reach2)] = counter + 1;
         }
       }
     }
   }
   counter++;
 }
```

Comment: Most of the time, streams are not faster than traditional while loops... take a look at this 
https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html#:~:text=Yes%2C%20streams%20are%20sometimes%20slower,are%20no%20faster%20than%20loops.&text=The%20point%20of%20streams%20is%20easy%20parallelization%20for%20better%20performance.  ... can you please add your board and your Pos class?

Comment: However ... in this case the code is converting a stream to an array and then iterating the array.

Comment: Hmm, the Board and Pos class are over 400 lines long, I'll try to scoop out the relevant methods

Comment: I'm not sure that is necessary. Wait a bit.  I'm working on an answer.

Comment: Alright, much thanks :)

Comment: Both currently upvoted answers call `currentTurn.getBoard().index(reach2)` twice.  I've provided an answer which avoids that.  Even if that method uses a `HashMap` to lookup the index, this should still be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the loop to a stream:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);
while (check(board, counter.get())) {
   for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
     if (board[i] == counter.get()) {
         Board.getReachables(currentTurn.getBoard().pos(i), currentTurn.getBoard())
         .filter(reach2 ->  board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(reach2)] == 0)
         .forEach(reach2 -> board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(reach2)] = counter.get() + 1);
     }
   }
   counter.incrementAndGet();
 }
```

`counter` converted to `AtomicInteger` because it is referred to within a lambda and must therefore be *effectively final*.

Other refactorings left to the reader.

Comment: This is a neat solution and more performant than what I have there. Thanks.

Comment: np. You could tidy up the code by introducing a variable whose value is `currentTurn.getBoard()`, and possibly another variable inside the loop for `counter + 1`, leaving `counter` as an `int`, to get around the “effectively final” issue. However, I strove to make the conversion as 1 to 1 as I could to focus on the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested and just an idea:

```
    while (check(board, counter)) {
        final int finalCounter = counter; //counter has to be final,
        //otherwise you get a "Local variable counter defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" error

        Arrays.stream(board) //IntStream
        .filter(b -> b == finalCounter) //  if (board[i] == counter) {
        .mapToObj(i ->Board.getReachables(currentTurn.getBoard().pos(i), currentTurn.getBoard())) //returns Stream<Stream<Pos>>
        .flatMap(Function.identity()) // flatmap maps Stream<Stream<Pos>> to a single (combined) Stream<Pos>
        .filter(pos -> board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(pos)] == 0)  //board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(reach2)] == 0
        .forEach(fp -> board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(fp)] = finalCounter +1); //board[currentTurn.getBoard().index(reach2)] = counter + 1;
        counter++;
    }
```

I don't think that someone should do it this way, but it was an interesting exercise.

Comment: I'm testing this right now, it seems to be the most performant solution so far :)

Comment: I might've spoken too soon. I'm using a search tree which has dynamic depth, and while this seems to be the most performant on depth 1, it slows down as soon as it goes deeper down the search tree. However, that might be due to the speed of the code making the tree go deeper faster, which might be the fault of my dynamic depth function. I'll keep testing

Comment: You could try to use Arrays.stream(board).parallel() instead of Arrays.stream(board) ... which sometimes is faster, but sometimes its slower ... you also have to check that your logic works when executed in parallel

Comment: I'm already doing calculations on parallel, splitting up the search tree to different threads. It might be smarter to split this method up instead of the search tree though.

Answer (score 0):

Two things will increase performance:

1. Don't create the array and loop over it, instead just call `.forEach` on the `Stream`.
2. Only calculate the index once.  Unfortunately this means using `if` instead of `.filter()`

```
        int counter = 1;
        while (check(board, counter)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                if (board[i] == counter) {
                    Board currentTurnBoard = currentTurn.getBoard();
                    int   nextCounter      = counter + 1;
                    Board.getReachables(currentTurnBoard.pos(i), currentTurnBoard)
                         .forEach(reach2 -> {
                             int index = currentTurnBoard.index(reach2);
                             if (board[index] == 0) {
                                 board[index] = nextCounter;
                             }
                             return;
                         });
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }
```